# Referenced Assembly is missing latest updates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build, assemblies, projects-and-solutions

I have two Visual Studio solutions. First is a class library that I share among all my projects. Second is the website I am currently working on. I compiled the library into a DLL and and referenced the DLL (not the project) in the second site.

Recently I made some updates in the library and overwrote the referenced DLL in the second solution with the new DLL. However, when I rebuild the solution, the DLL that makes it to the `/bin` does not have the new code. I have:

- Checked the referenced DLL in Reflector.
- Removed and re-referenced the new DLL in the projects.
- Manually checked the reference in the project's XML.

Everything looks correct and is pulling from the right places. All projects are .NET 3.5.

What gives? How is it that the referenced assembly has the updated code but the assembly that gets copied to the `/bin` doesn't have the new code?

**UPDATE**

I manually copied the referenced DLL into the site's `/bin` after the build and everything ran as expected. Is there a reference somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: That's a weird one. Did you try right clicking on the solution and checking the Configuration Manager? Maybe you don't have the referenced dll set to build, or something is screwy with Debug/Release configurations? Did you check the Output window to make sure there are no build errors (maybe an access denied or something similar)?

Comment: Forgetting to build the Release version of that assembly jumps to mind.

Comment: No build errors. Investigating the Debug/Release point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting and re-adding the references a few dozen more times, it seems to be working now. I have no idea what it was that caused the problem. I don't want to say that the *"problem exists between the keyboard and chair"* but I'm not sure what else it could have been since nothing really changed.